# iOS 7 or 8 - combining iAd with MapKit

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, mapkit, iad

When you open a map with MapKit, it displays a small "Legal" link near the bottom which you can access for a lot of legal stuff. According to the guidelines, this link must not be interfered with to prevent it from functioning. I don't even know if it can be moved.

At the same time, the recommended placement of ads from iAd is at the bottom of the screen. Makes sense because that's where the fingers are. But placing the ad there will overlap the link and prevent it from being accessed.

I was wondering if anyone has set up iAds so that instead of overlaying the main screen, it reduces the size of the main screen, and positions itself "next" to it?

I'm thinking if I do this with other controls at the bottom, then would that inconvenience users who are trying to access the controls, only to have an ad slip underneath?

Would it be better to go against recommendation and put the ad at the top?

Comment: Can you try a quick experiment? What happens if you just set `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` in your view controller's viewDidLoad? (The default behaviour of canDisplayBannerAds is to do exactly what you describe, but I don't know how it interacts with MapKit...)

Comment: @MattGibson - I'm not seeing `canDisplayBannerAds` as a property, but the default configuration seems to overlay the link.

Comment: @MattGibson - Figured it out -- after a test compile I could see `canDisplayBannerAds`. Yes, setting `canDisplayBannerAds` does appear to move the link up. I will test to see if it moves it back down once the ads stop.

Comment: @MattGibson - If you provide a placeholder answer "Please read comments above." I can mark it as correct and you can get your points. /YR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the simplest solution possible: set the `canDisplayBannerAds` property of your view controller to `true`; this should handle pushing display ads up from the bottom and resizing the existing views.